# z-index HTML. Не понимаю почему не работает

Tags: html, css

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 5px solid gray;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.target {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: darkseagreen;
  width: 100px;
  height: 85px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  right: 518px;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <p>
            Veggies es bonus vobis, proinde vos postulo essum magis kohlrabi welsh onion daikon 
            amaranth tatsoi tomatillo melon azuki bean garlic.
        </p>
        <div class="target">
            Target
        </div>
        <p>
            Gumbo beet greens corn soko endive gumbo gourd. Parsley shallot courgette tatsoi pea 
            sprouts fava bean collard greens dandelion okra wakame tomato. Dandelion cucumber 
            earthnut pea peanut soko zucchini.
        </p>
  </div>
```

Почему когда я Таргету прописываю z-index: 0, то у меня он не уходит на второй план? Я хочу чтобы текст не закрывал

Comment: Поставьте `z-index: -1;`

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Многие ошибочно думают, что `z-index` работает, например, как слои в Photoshop, и числовое значение `z-index` будет неким "порядковым номером" в иерархии слоёв.

Но это не так, у каждого элемента по умолчанию `z-index` равен нулю.
Т.е. если вы хотите, чтобы текущий элемент "уходил на второй план", т.е. был "за" своим родителем, то требуется указать `z-index: -1;`, но даже тут есть нюансы:

> Если несколько элементов имеют одно и то же значение `z-index` (т.е. они расположены на одном и том же слое), применяются правила наложения, поясненные в разделе [Наложение без использования свойства z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_positioned_layout/Understanding_z-index/Stacking_without_z-index).

---

Более подробно про `z-index` - [Понимание CSS z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_positioned_layout/Understanding_z-index)